# Rendering video with Blender on Pop!_os

Tags: pop-os, video-editing, blender

I have been using blender as a video editor for a few years now, but it has always rendered very slowly. I worry that I've installed a few too many drivers and something has gotten mixed up at some point.

For unrelated reasons, I'm about to do an OS re-install so I will have a clean Pop!_os installation with the default video drivers (mesa, if I'm not mistaken).

1. What version of blender should I install?
2. What drivers should I install, if any, for my Radeon RX 5600 gpu?

Comment: hey, I'm removing the "can you link me to a tutorial" from your question, because a) it's already pretty broad, and b) questions asking for such materials are actually off-topic by our close rules.

Comment: @MarcusMüller my apologies, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What version of blender should I install?

The most recent one. I happen to know Aras Pranckevičius recently worked on the video editor performance

> What drivers should I install, if any, for my Radeon RX 5600 gpu?

The AMD open source ones; AMDGPU.

Comment: Are those compatible with Blender gpu cycle rendering, as opposed to something like openCL and HIP?

Comment: I don't know what that is. However, you have no other choice than that drivers, so, honestly: probably, but you couldn't change it if they weren't.